# How to see the newest uploads in a particular search phrase in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I'm noticing for some time that the 'sort by date' filter is misbehaving. Apparently they only sort the first several dozen relevant videos by upload date. Instead of showing me the newest uploads. Or at least it's some mixture of the two: you may see maybe a dozen of new uploads, but after that, the upload dates rapidly decreasing and you'll find videos on the 5-10th serp that are uploaded months or years ago, if you go further you get crap results, without any particular ordering. But the phrase I search for is active and has several uploads almost each day, so if they would show me the newest ones I shouldn't see such old videos on the 5th page.

I don't know what are they doing, but I wonder is there a way to see the newest uploads?

Or maybe is there a way to set up a notification for that phrase so I can keep myself up to date?